# Как изменить цвет части прямоугольника по клику мыши HTML,JS?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, canvas

Задача: При наведении курсора мыши на любую часть прямоугольника, по клику изменяется цвет данного участка.

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Вопрос:

Понимаю как изменить весь фон по клику мыши в js, но не знаю как это сделать на определенном участке данной фигуры. Участок с изменяемым цветом квадратной формы, высоту и шире можно изменять.

Как это можно реализовать с помощью HTML,JS? Какие для это нужны методы?
или же эту задачу можно решить  только  с фигурой нарисованной в Canvasa'e и его функций?

Comment: А сам что сделал?  Что не получается? Советую хотя бы выложить исходник. Какие участки, как они должны быть распределены по родителю, какой формы участки, что именно ты питаешься сделать?  сформируй вопрос надлежащим образом, чтобы получить адекватный ответ...

Comment: Ответ может варьироваться в зависимости от задачи. если что-то рисуется на canvas'е, то и изменять надо с помощью его функций. Поэтому без тщательного описания вопроса что есть и что **точно** надо - ничего сказать нельзя

Comment: Не понятно мне какие для того нужно использовать методы, свойства js, html. И в первую очередь, интересно можно ли это сделать без фигуры нарисованной в canavasa'e

Comment: Можно сделать на SVG. Просто добавлять квадрат заданных параметров поверх фигуры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery подход: динамически генерируем в целевом блоке некое количество блоков-потомков и уже их заполняем цветом по клику.

```js
var $square = $(".square"),
    pieces_x = 10, // кол-во блоков по горизонтали
    pieces_y = 5,  // кол-во блоков по вертикали
    pieces = pieces_x * pieces_y,
    colors = ['red','green','blue','yellow','brown','orange','white','black','purple','coral','indigo','lime'];
    
for(i = 0; i < pieces; i++) {
    $square.append("<div class='color-me' style='width:" + 100 / pieces_x + "%;height:" + 100 / pieces_y + "%;float:left;'></div>");
}

$(".color-me").click(function() {

    $(this).css({
        'background-color' : colors[ Math.floor((Math.random() * colors.length)) ]
    });
});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #9acd32;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо, за ответ.